# Does google directions api duration reflect real time traffic?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, duration, map-directions

I have been following [android get duration from maps.google.com directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951007/android-get-duration-from-maps-google-com-directions) and I seem to be doing okay, but I have a question: does the duration returned in the JSON from google maps adjust for real time traffic?

Comment: Google API team? Anyone there? Chris Broadfoot?

Comment: I have a related question on [Android Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20493/why-does-google-maps-display-routes-waypoints-differently-on-phone-than-on-pc)

Answer (score 2):

From the definitions on the google [developers documentation for directions api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Legs) :

- duration indicates the total duration of this leg
- duration_in_traffic indicates the total duration of this leg, taking into account current traffic conditions

I would take this to mean that no, duration doesn't not adjust for real time traffic.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to determine the answer to the question empirically by getting the duration at different times of day. I think you'll find it is not real-time based.

The documentation does not make mention of real-time traffic. While that's not conclusive, accounting for real-time traffic conditions would be rather a coup and highly likely to be included.