# android find distance and duration between two points on google map

Tags: android, google-maps

i followed the tut in this here https://inducesmile.com/android/android-find-distance-and-duration-between-two-points-on-android-map/

everything seems to be working , only 2 error that i got and everyone who followed the tut

first in MapsActivity

```
private List<LatLng> getDirectionPolylines(List<RouteObject> routes){
        List<LatLng> directionList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        for(RouteObject route : routes){
            List<LegsObject> legs = route.getLegs();
            for(LegsObject leg : legs){
                String routeDistance = leg.getDistance().getText(); HERE
                String routeDuration = leg.getDuration().getText(); HERE
                setRouteDistanceAndDuration(routeDistance, routeDuration); // here we will send the route Duration and distent
                List<StepsObject> steps = leg.getSteps();
                for(StepsObject step : steps){
                    PolylineObject polyline = step.getPolyline();
                    String points = polyline.getPoints();
                    List<LatLng> singlePolyline = decodePoly(points);
                    for (LatLng direction : singlePolyline){
                        directionList.add(direction);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return directionList;
    }
```

error

```
Cannot resolve method 'getText()
```

second error is in LegsObject class

```
import java.util.List;


public class LegsObject {
    private List<StepsObject> steps;

    private DistanceObject distance;

    private DurationObject duration;

    public LegsObject(DurationObject duration, DistanceObject distance, List<StepsObject> steps) {
        this.duration = duration;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.steps = steps;
    }

    public List<StepsObject> getSteps() {
        return steps;
    }

    public DistanceObject getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public DurationObject getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
}
```

error

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'DistanceObject'
Cannot resolve symbol 'DurationObject'
```

i believe if the second error in LegsObject.class fixed the first error will be fixed as well

Comment: your DistanceObject class is missing it seems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a third party library for this. It's easy and efficient:

Gradle Dependancy:

```
compile 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.4' // Custom Google Direction API \\
```

Code:

Below method will take the latLng of your destination, also inside method you should have latlng object containing your origin. Server key is your api key and you should also enable Google Directions API to make this work.

```
/**
     * Draw polyline on map, get distance and duration of the route
     *
     * @param latLngDestination LatLng of the destination
     */
    private void getDestinationInfo(LatLng latLngDestination) {
        progressDialog();
        String serverKey = getResources().getString(R.string.google_direction_api_key); // Api Key For Google Direction API \\
        final LatLng origin = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        final LatLng destination = latLngDestination;
        //-------------Using AK Exorcist Google Direction Library---------------\\
        GoogleDirection.withServerKey(serverKey)
                .from(origin)
                .to(destination)
                .transportMode(TransportMode.DRIVING)
                .execute(new DirectionCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {
                        dismissDialog();
                        String status = direction.getStatus();
                        if (status.equals(RequestResult.OK)) {
                            Route route = direction.getRouteList().get(0);
                            Leg leg = route.getLegList().get(0);
                            Info distanceInfo = leg.getDistance();
                            Info durationInfo = leg.getDuration();
                            String distance = distanceInfo.getText();
                            String duration = durationInfo.getText();

                            //------------Displaying Distance and Time-----------------\\
                            showingDistanceTime(distance, duration); // Showing distance and time to the user in the UI \\
//                            String message = "Total Distance is " + distance + " and Estimated Time is " + duration;
//                            StaticMethods.customSnackBar(consumerHomeActivity.parentLayout, message,
//                                    getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary),
//                                    getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite), 3000);

                            //--------------Drawing Path-----------------\\
                            ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionList = leg.getDirectionPoint();
                            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = DirectionConverter.createPolyline(getActivity(),
                                    directionPositionList, 5, getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                            googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                            //--------------------------------------------\\

                            //-----------Zooming the map according to marker bounds-------------\\
                            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                            builder.include(origin);
                            builder.include(destination);
                            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

                            int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                            int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
                            int padding = (int) (width * 0.20); // offset from edges of the map 10% of screen

                            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, padding);
                            googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
                            //------------------------------------------------------------------\\

                        } else if (status.equals(RequestResult.NOT_FOUND)) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "No routes exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
                        // Do something here
                    }
                });
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\

    }
```

Comment: Try it and tell me!

Comment: after all i found out that your ans is much easier and work just fine

Comment: Thanks brother.. It would be great if you accept my answer... It will help others... Also upvote it if you liked it...

Comment: sure Done , can u see my other Q maybe you could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788397/how-to-run-function2-after-function1-finish-android Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

there is no implementation of :

1) DistanceObject class

2) DurationObject class

```
public class DistanceObject{


    private Integer value;
    private String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**same class for duration**

```
public class DurationObject {

    private String text;

    private Integer value;


    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**to get distance**

```
Integer disInMeters=routeA.getLegs().get(0).getDistance().getValue();
int  kilometers = (int) (disInMeters * 0.001); //convert in KM
```

**to get duration**

```
Integer duration=routeA.getLegs().get(0).getDuration().getValue();
```

for more help follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951007/android-get-duration-from-maps-google-com-directions)